# php imap_search filter

Tags: php, email, imap, codeigniter-2

I need to filter the Email from INBOX by filter `FROM` address.

What i have is email address of a particular user say `user@example.com` and i dont have his name/nickName/ContactName On MAIL etc

How can i get all mail from this user using his Email address ?

I tried

```
$some   = imap_search($con, 'FROM "user@example.com"', SE_UID);         
var_dump($some);
```

and it returns `FALSE`

But the following one works

```
 $some   = imap_search($con, 'FROM "user"', SE_UID);            
    var_dump($some);
```

Please note that `user` is his name ,but i need to filter it using the actual email address,

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double-quotes that are wrapping the email address.

```
$some   = imap_search($con, 'FROM user@example.com', SE_UID)
```